# Published Application in ClickOnce does not show updates

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I am creating a WPF application and publishes it on the IIS. However when I am re-publishing the application since I do have code and UI changes, it doesn't show the changes on the application when I run it.

Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Do you use a proxy to access the application?

Comment: @bniwredyo - No. Actually I've been using clickonce deployment before but its my first time to use it in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out! It has something to do with the publish version. I am not incrementing the publish version since I am just publishing minor changes but the consequence is that ClickOnce will not let the application to download the updates from the server since the last version on the client is same as the publish version on the server and ClickOnce assumes the client is already updated.

Answer (score 2):

These may be some of those obvious checks you have already done:

- Have you checked that the version number is higher and the application did in fact update?
- Has the application been set to automatically update?

Is this a online-only or offline mode application?

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo - Thanks but I already found out why. Its on the publish version. The application didn't update itself since the publish version on the client is same on the server. Thanks anyway!